# Saving a form with text and checboxes to text file

Tags: php, html, forms, text

I an working on a HTML form to help me keep track on information when I play roll playing games.
The form has a grid of checkboxes that are used to track health. I also have a text box that I track other stats in.

I want to have a 2 buttons: LOAD and SAVE.
When save is hit the current status (whether or not a box is marked), if every form element is saved to a text file Save/save.txt. Any information in a existing text file should be replaced. I only care about the current settings.
when load is hit the data is loaded from the text file and the form is filled out like it was when it was saved.

How do I get this form to save / load?

```
<form action="HP_Tracker.php" method="post">
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
  <tr>
    <td><center><b>W</b></center></td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td bgcolor="ffffff"><input name="W1" type="checkbox" value="" /></td>
    <td bgcolor="000000"><input name="S24" type="checkbox" value="" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td bgcolor="ffffff"><input name="W2" type="checkbox" value="" /></td>
    <td bgcolor="000000"><input name="S23" type="checkbox" value="" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td bgcolor="F0F0F5"><input name="W3" type="checkbox" value="" /></td>
    <td bgcolor="0A0A0F"><input name="S22" type="checkbox" value="" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td bgcolor="E0E0EB"><input name="W4" type="checkbox" value="" /></td>
    <td bgcolor="14141F"><input name="S21" type="checkbox" value="" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td bgcolor="D1D1E0"><input name="W5" type="checkbox" value="" /></td>
    <td bgcolor="1F1F2E"><input name="S20" type="checkbox" value="" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td bgcolor="C2C2D6"><input name="W6" type="checkbox" value="" /></td>
    <td bgcolor="29293D"><input name="S19" type="checkbox" value="" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td bgcolor="B2B2CC"><input name="W7" type="checkbox" value="" /></td>
    <td bgcolor="33334C"><input name="S18" type="checkbox" value="" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td bgcolor="A3A3C2"><input name="W8" type="checkbox" value="" /></td>
    <td bgcolor="3D3D5C"><input name="S17" type="checkbox" value="" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td bgcolor="9494B8"><input name="W9" type="checkbox" value="" /></td>
    <td bgcolor="47476B"><input name="S16" type="checkbox" value="" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td bgcolor="8585AD"><input name="W10" type="checkbox" value="" /></td>
    <td bgcolor="52527A"><input name="S15" type="checkbox" value="" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td bgcolor="7575A3"><input name="W11" type="checkbox" value="" /></td>
    <td bgcolor="5C5C8A"><input name="S14" type="checkbox" value="" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td bgcolor="666699"><input name="W12" type="checkbox" value="" /></td>
    <td bgcolor="666699"><input name="S13" type="checkbox" value="" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td bgcolor="5C5C8A"><input name="W13" type="checkbox" value="" /></td>
    <td bgcolor="7575A3"><input name="S12" type="checkbox" value="" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td bgcolor="52527A"><input name="W14" type="checkbox" value="" /></td>
    <td bgcolor="8585AD"><input name="S11" type="checkbox" value="" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td bgcolor="47476B"><input name="W15" type="checkbox" value="" /></td>
    <td bgcolor="9494B8"><input name="S10" type="checkbox" value="" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td bgcolor="3D3D5C"><input name="W16" type="checkbox" value="" /></td>
    <td bgcolor="A3A3C2"><input name="S9" type="checkbox" value="" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td bgcolor="33334C"><input name="W17" type="checkbox" value="" /></td>
    <td bgcolor="B2B2CC"><input name="S8" type="checkbox" value="" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td bgcolor="29293D"><input name="W18" type="checkbox" value="" /></td>
    <td bgcolor="C2C2D6"><input name="S7" type="checkbox" value="" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td bgcolor="1F1F2E"><input name="W19" type="checkbox" value="" /></td>
    <td bgcolor="D1D1E0"><input name="S6" type="checkbox" value="" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td bgcolor="14141F"><input name="W20" type="checkbox" value="" /></td>
    <td bgcolor="E0E0EB"><input name="S5" type="checkbox" value="" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td bgcolor="0A0A0F"><input name="W21" type="checkbox" value="" /></td>
    <td bgcolor="F0F0F5"><input name="S4" type="checkbox" value="" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td bgcolor="000000"><input name="W22" type="checkbox" value="" /></td>
    <td bgcolor="FFFFFF"><input name="S3" type="checkbox" value="" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td bgcolor="000000"><input name="W23" type="checkbox" value="" /></td>
    <td bgcolor="FFFFFF"><input name="S2" type="checkbox" value="" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td bgcolor="000000"><input name="W24" type="checkbox" value="" /></td>
    <td bgcolor="FFFFFF"><input name="S1" type="checkbox" value="" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td><center><b>S</b></center></td>
  </tr>
</table>

<hr />
Initiative<br />
<input name="Initiative" type="text" size="4" />

<br /><br />
<input name="Save" type="submit" value="SAVE" />

</form>
```

Comment: Suggest you try at least to save something with serialize()

Comment: Haven't seen `bgcolor="..."` since ages ...

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: How do I get this form to save / load?

Comment: there are several file functions you would want to check in php.net or google: fopen, fwrite, file_get_contents, file_put_contents

Answer (score 0):

Try that:

```
<?php

if (!empty($_POST)) {
    $data     = implode(',', $_POST);
    $fileName = 'yourFile.txt';
    $file     = fopen($fileName, 'a+');

    fwrite($file, $data); 
    fclose($file);
    chmod(0777);
}
```

Comment: Are you sure? You have to add this code in your "HP_Tracker.php" file and create a text file (named "yourFile.txt" in the code).

Comment: i got it to work, not sure what the problem. i did change 'a+' to 'w+'. This is becuase I only care about the last state of the form and wanted older states deleted when a new one is saved. now i ned to figure out how to load hte data from the text file to populate the form, but at least I am half way there.